# Returning a class instance from a module?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, module, persistence

I have a class I created, and in a module, I create an instance of the class. Unfortunately as it is now, whenever the module ends, so does the class instance (as expected). I want to keep that class instance, and I tried a return (className) but it did nothing.

What's the best way to get that class instance to persist?

Comment: Keep it *where*? Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sure. I have a class Person, with the def __init__ setting initial values for name and age. In module addFunc(), I create a new instance of person with person1 = Person(inputName), where inputName was a name they entered. That part works fine, but the problem is, whenever addFunc() ends, my person1 disappears.

Comment: No, I mean some actual formatted code, in the question itself, that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @iu34: module and function are completely different. Local variables exist only during the function call. Module variable are practically immortal in Python unless you explicitly remove them. Please, clarify what do you mean by "returning a class instance from a module". [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26193396/edit), don't put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`addFunc()` would appear to be a *function*, not a *module*.

If you want `person1` to persist after the function has returned, return the `person1` object from the function and bind it to a variable in the outer scope. For example:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def addFunc(inputName):
    person1 = Person(inputName)
    return person1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    person = addFunc('iu34')
    print person.name
```

Now `person1` is returned from addFunc and bound to `person`.

There are alternatives such as passing a dictionary or list into `addFunc()`, and storing the created `Person` object there - it depends on your application.

Comment: In this case there's really no need for `addFunc` at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : one would assume that there is more to `addFunc` than simply creating a `Person`, and the implementation I've shown is just to demonstrate the concept.